# Рабочий цикл процессора

Tags: циклы, процессор

Сдаю экзамен по ЭВМ, на тему "Рабочий цикл процессора". Преподавателем была предложена для изучения Книга "Каган Б.М. Электронные вычислительные машины и системы", в ней на стр. 297 имеется схема: [image: введите сюда описание изображения] и пояснение к ней:

> ...Рабочий цикл начинается с распознавания состояния про- цессора.
>   Устанавливается, какое из альтернативных состоя- ний — Счет или
>   Ожидание — имеет место. Далее проверяется наличие незамаскированных
>   прерываний.
>
> В состоянии Ожидание никакие программы не выполняются. Процессор ждет
>   прихода запроса прерывания, после чего управ- ление переходит к
>   соответствующей прерывающей программе, переводящей процессор в
>   состояние Счет.
>
> В состоянии Счет при наличии незамаскированных прерыва- ний происходят
>   выход из нормального рабочего цикла и переход к процедуре обработки
>   запросов прерывання.
>
> При отсутствии в состоянии Счет запросов прерывания по- следовательно
>   выполняются этапы рабочего цикла: выборка очередной команды и
>   определение по коду операции команды ее группы, подготовка операндов
>   (формирование исполнительных адресов и выборка операндов из памяти),
>   обработка операндов в АЛУ и запоминание результата...

Преподаватель задает вопрос "Чего ожидает процессор?" и утверждает что ответ на этой схеме есть. Отвечал что "Процессор ждет прихода запроса прерывания" как об этом говорится в книге, на что был получен ответ что это не так и процессор ждет чего то другого. 
Прошу помочь разобраться чего же именно ожидает процессор?

Comment: Ну, если препод не принимает ответ "Ждет прерывания", то, возможно, процессор ждет очередного такта от генератора частот.

Comment: Думаю это уже слишком глубоко :)
Опять же, препод говорит что ответ есть на "картинке", а там ни про такты, ни про частоту ничего нет

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Посмотрите в правый нижний угол.  Там есть блок "Перевод процессора в режим Ожидания "  к которому переход осуществляется при невыполнение условия "Канал и ПУ свободны" . Возможно,  имеется в виду,, что процессор ожидает освобождения канала и ПУ?

Не могу писать комментарии,  поэтому добавлю сюда.
1. На сколько помню,  HALT все же не режим ожидания,  в режим останова,  это разные вещи.
2.Если я правильно понимаю диаграмму,  тогда то,  что на ней изображено - очень далеко от операционной системы,  это уровень микропрограмм и аппаратный реализации.
3. Процессор действительно не "ждет" прерывания.  Ждать он может чего-либо, необходимого для продолжения выполнения основного алгоритма функционирования.  А на прерывания процессор просто реагирует по мере их появления.

Comment: Похоже на правду, попробую воспользоваться данным ответом. Сам уже не понимаю что от меня хотят и просто перебираю все потенциально возможные варианты. Спасибо

Comment: Ваш вариант "процессор ожидает освобождения канала и ПУ" оказался верным. Спасибо, выручили :)

Answer (score 0):

Процессор ожидает прерывания, и ничего другого ожидать не может. Из состояния ожидания прерывания его может вывести только прерывание или аппаратный сброс. Например, вот что говорится в описании команды HLT процессора x86:

> HLT stops instruction execution and places the x86 in a HALT state. An
>   enabled interrupt, NMI, or a reset will resume execution.

Ваша схема, кстати, рисует это неправильно. Судя по ней, процессор ждет прерывания в цикле. На самом деле он по этой команде просто уходит в спячку.

И еще не совсем понятен термин "запрос прерывания". Видимо, подразумевается аппаратный сигнал прерывания на ножке процессора, но для программиста эти тонкости уже неразличимы. Мы говорим просто "пришло прерывание".

Comment: Считаю точно так же и, возможно, именно по этому данный вопрос вызывает у меня такие трудности. Тем не менее, это не решает моей проблемы, т. к. не смотря на все мои попытки донести информацию о прерываниях, преподаватель остается уверен в своей правоте. По этому все сводится к тому чтобы просто догадаться что именно он подразумевает. Спорить и что то доказывать бесполезно. Преподаватель так же говорил что процессор не ждет прерывания, а просто проверяет "между делом" есть ли оно и выполняет основную программу.

Comment: @Toshima, ну, это не мое мнение, а то, что написано в документации на процессор. Вообще вам стоит выяснить о каком процессоре преподаватель спрашивает, некоторые работают очень экзотично. И еще надо уточнить про какой уровень процессора речь. Потому что процессор работает очень по разному с точки зрения ОС и с точки зрения микропрограммы.

Comment: @freim, по поводу "запроса прерывания" и его неразличимости для программиста. Смотря на каком уровне разрабатывается программа. Если близко к железу, (например, для встроенных в прибор микроконтроллеров), то вполне различим и сигнал на ножке и запрос прерывания. Запросом прерывания, кстати, является флаг в регистре прерываний, формируемый аппаратно, и снимающийся при входе в обработчик прерывания.